# js event handler run once with removeEventListener

Tags: javascript

The following event would trigger console log once the button is pressed. But the console log will only have 1 output no matter how many times the button is pressed. I have two questions about the code:

1. why can you use the `once` inside its own definition?
2. why does "Done" only output once and stay there? When you `removeEventListener`, what makes the next clicks not run more `console.log`s ?

This is an example on [eloquent javascript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/15_event.html)

```
<button>Act-once button</button>
<script>
  let button = document.querySelector("button");
  function once() {
    console.log("Done.");
    button.removeEventListener("click", once);
  }
  button.addEventListener("click", once);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can you use the once inside its own definition?

That's how pretty much all programming languages work or else how would you implement recursion (function calling itself)?

> why does "Done" only output once and stay there?

Well, the logging output will remain visible in the console unless the console gets cleared or there's further logging which overflows the visible part of the console.

> When you removeEventListener, what makes the next clicks not run more console.logs ?

Because the event listener (`once`) which calls `console.log("Done.")` has been removed (that's what `removeEventListener(once)` does) and therefore won't get triggered for new click events.